# Three words using some same letters

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, letters

> I'm very smart indeed.
>
> If you remove my first letter, I become very accurate.
>
> Then, if you replace the removed letter with another one, I become the synonym of anagram 'CAPIN'.

What words are these?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are you

> BRIGHT?

Because

> you're smart if you're BRIGHT, you're accurate if you're RIGHT, and you might panic (anagram of CAPIN) if you have a FRIGHT.